# Using fgets( ) - the most memory efficient way

Tags: c, linux, memory, buffer, fgets

Looking around the online I have yet to find a definitive answer related to the `fgets()` character pointer array (char *restrict *s*) in terms of efficient memory allocation.

**synopsis:** `char *fgets(char *restrict s, int n, FILE *restrict stream);`

Looking at the `fgets()` - [**specification**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

From my understanding of this spec, you should be allocating based on the `LINE_MAX` macro defined in the `<limits.h>` - [**specification**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), simply because you don't know how many characters each line has.

If I run - `printf("LINE_MAX BYTES: %d\n", LINE_MAX);` the result is  `2048`.

That being said, declaring `char *line[LINE_MAX]` -or- `char *line[2048]` seems inefficiently large to me, however, this may be the best way of doing it?

//PROGRAM

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                  
#include <limits.h>                                                                                                 
int main(void){                                                                                                     
    char line[LINE_MAX];                                                                                   
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");                                                                          
    while(fgets(line, LINE_MAX + 1, fp)){                                                                           
        printf("%s", line);                                                                               
    }                                                                                                    
    fclose(fp);                                                                                                 
    return(0); 
}
```

//FILE (file.txt)

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Comment: `malloc` some memory, read char by char, use `realloc` if there is not enough buffer space, adding a percentage, or a fixed amount to its size.

Comment: Or `malloc()`, read via `fgets()`, and if you fill the buffer before reaching the end of the line then `realloc()` and read some more.

Comment: Really, though, 2048 bytes isn't all that many in most modern environments.  Certainly not enough that I would sweat it.  The real problem is that I don't think it's safe to rely on lines not exceeding `LINE_MAX` characters.

Comment: Also, if you go with static allocation then don't forget to allow `LINE_MAX + 1` characters, as you need space for a string terminator, too.

Comment: 2048 bytes is a tiny amount of memory on modern machines. So yes, you should `fgets` into a fixed size buffer known to be big enough to hold the longest line. You can then `strdup`, or `malloc`/`strcpy` to store the line in a correctly sized buffer for later use. If you don't need to store the lines (i.e. each line is fully processed before the next line is read), then just use the fixed sized buffer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yea agree I think dynamic allocation would be the best approach over static, since your allocating on a per line size... but how would I got about doing that? I need to get the line character count?

Comment: @JordanDavis, you start with a guess at how long a "reasonable" line can be, and allocate that much.  After calling `fgets()`, if it succeeds, you can determine the line length via `strlen()`.  Alternatively, you can initialize the bytes at the end of the buffer to, say `\x7f`, `\7f`, and check after `fgets()` whether it ends with `\0` preceded by something other than `\n`.  If it does, then `fgets()` exhausted the buffer and you need to enlarge it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger got it makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you are using a Posix-2008 compatible system (Linux, OS X, FreeBSD, etc. but not Windows afaik), you can use [getline](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getline.3.html). To avoid excess allocations, if you don't need to save the  line read, pass it the same buffer pointer each time; start by initializing it to NULL. When you've read the entire file, free() the buffer. `getline` will only reallocate when necessary (so it will no longer do so after it reads the longest line).

Comment: lets start with the prototype for fgets() does not include an 'restrict' modifiers.   The 'restrict' modifier is useful for promising the compiler that that something like a memcpy() will not have overlapping operands.  For fgets() it would be meaningless.

Comment: after calling certain system functions, like `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the local variable 'result' is unused, causes the compiler to output a warning, and should be removed.    This line: `while(fgets(line, LINE_MAX + 1, fp)){ ` can/will result in undefined behaviour because `line` is only LINE_MAX characters long, so a line in the input file that is >= LINE_MAX characters will write past the end of the buffer.   Suggest: `while(fgets(line, LINE_MAX, fp)){ `

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Linux 14.04.   The limits.h file does not contain any definition for 'LINE_MAX'   Strongly suggest removing: `#include <limits.h>`  and inserting: `#define LINE_MAX (2048)`

Comment: The printf() format string should not have a '\n' because the line[] array will have a '\n' from each line read from the file.   When the format string also contains a '\n' then the output will be double spaced

Comment: @user3629249 the 'restrict' is simply representational of a char pointer array as specified in the synopsis... Yes I left error checking out for clarity... Once again result isn't initialize so I have no idea what your talking about  when you say it's unused and causes in error... If you look at the spec, even the example uses LINE_MAX + 1 to make room for the \n character... my LIMITS.H does have it and you should check what your OS defines as a maximum line is since it could be larger or smaller then (2048).

Comment: the posted code has a stray '}' way out to the right on the line: `return(0);`

Comment: Your right on the '}' and the printf \n I'll update it.

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings.  then the posted code will show (at least) the 'warning' about the unused variable 'result' AND an 'error' about the unexpected '}' at the end of the posted code.   Please read the man page for the syntax for the 'fgets()'  You will notice that there are NO 'restrict' modifiers on the first and third parameters

Comment: @user3629249 I don't understand why you say their is a variable `result` being unused... in the synopsis of `fgets()` result is just what they use to represent a char pointer array, in my code im not using result, I'm using line... please explain how a variable name `result` is being initialized.

Comment: @user3629249 never mind your right I forgot to remove that from my code when I posted it, I'll update that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your file has some special properties, allocating `LINE_MAX` bytes is the best approach. Although you may be wasting some memory there, allocation in the automatic memory is really cheap, because the space is being "reserved" more than "allocated", with lots of hardware support on most modern architectures.

On the other hand, if you know that due to the format of your file the lines cannot exceed a certain length `MY_LINE`, you could use `MY_LINE+2`<sup>*</sup> as your limit instead:

```
char line[MY_LINE+2];
```

For example, a program reading a file in `uuendode` format needs at most 62 characters per line, so it could define

```
#define MY_LINE 62
```

<sup>*</sup> Assuming you're on UNIX, you need space for `'\n'` and `'\0'`, hence the `+2` part. If you are on Windows, do +3 to accommodate the additional `'\r'` character.

Comment: For my case use I won't know the line size, I'll be getting file from a url that has a variable length in terms of line sizes... so I want it to be robust to handle a variable in terms of size, but I'm also thinking about efficiency. I think dynamic allocation would be the best solution, allocating based on a per/line scenario.

Comment: @JordanDavis The catch here is that you do not know the length of the line until you read it. In addition, `malloc` is generally orders of magnitude slower than automatic (AKA "stack") allocations. On top of that, using `malloc`/`free` for each line may result in fragmentation if the code in between also makes allocations.

Comment: okay yea that def makes sense and understand that I would loose a lot in terms of performance/speed... I probably wouldn't use the dynamic allocation as I mentioned above for this reason you just mentioned lol, but just for understanding purposes... how would I go  about getting the character line count?  read character-by-character till I come across the "\n" character ?

Comment: @JordanDavis Reading character-by-character can be done, but it is too slow an exercise. You could allocate some small buffer - say, 100 characters, read into it until you get less than a buffer full of characters, or the last character of the string happens to be `'\n'`. If you get a full buffer with no `'\n'` at the end, add 100 to your running total, and read on. Eventually you would either get to the end of file, or a string with `'\n'` somewhere in its body. Add the position to the running total for your final result.

Comment: makes sense once again, yea I don't think I'll be using char-by-char lol, just curious. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: on Windows/DOS system , '\n' is actually 2 characters so that would be a +3, not a +2

Comment: @user3629249 Edited. By the way, feel free to edit answers when you wish to add small things like that.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
cleanly compiles
performs error checking
```

If a line is too long, the partial line will be echo'd then the next call to fgets() will obtain some more of the line, which will be echo'd, ect.   No output will be lost and no undefined behaviour will be performed.

you could use 'getline()' instead of fgets(), but why bother.  Using getline() will make the code more complex, without adding any functionality and (as others have commented) a 2048 byte buffer is trivial on todays' computers.

If your really worried about the buffer size.  The following could use a buffer as small as 2 bytes for linux/mac (3 bytes for windows/DOS) and still work correctly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINE_MAX (2048)

int main(void)
{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINE_MAX (2048)

int main(void)
{

    char line[LINE_MAX];

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    if( NULL ==( fp = fopen("file.txt", "r") ) )
    {
        perror( "fopen for file.txt for read failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    while( fgets(line, LINE_MAX, fp) )
    {
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}

    char line[LINE_MAX];

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    if( NULL ==( fp = fopen("file.txt", "r") ) )
    {
        perror( "fopen for file.txt for read failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    while( fgets(line, LINE_MAX, fp) )
    {
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but I believe you pasted it twice, take a look at it.

Comment: Also just noticed something, both in my code and in yours.... shouldn't the `line[LINE_MAX]` really be a pointer, because in the synopsis it lists it as `char *restrict s` ?

Comment: @JordanDavis, what synopsis?   for 'fgets()'?  the first parameter is a pointer to a buffer.  in C, an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the buffer, so, no 'line[LINE_MAX]' should not be a pointer.   Thanks for noticing the dual paste,  Just goes to show, when I'm tired, I make more than (the usual number) of mistakes

Comment: yea for `fgets()`, the first param of fgets() is `char *restrict s` I understand what a char *pointer is, but why is there  a "restrict" in there? and also were not defining a pointer array, were creating a char array so we really should declare the char array `line[LINE_MAX]` like we have and then set set a pointer to it called `s` (for example purposes), no?